# Azure Stream Analytics npm package doesn't work for yaml pipeline

Tags: azure, npm, stream, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm using Azure Stream Analytics CI/CD npm package https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/cicd-tools?tabs=visual-studio-code to build a project. I added below steps in my yaml pipeline:

```
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'Install Stream Analytics CI/CD package'
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    customCommand: 'install -g azure-streamanalytics-cicd'

- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Build Stream Analytics project'
  inputs:
    script: 'azure-streamanalytics-cicd build -project $(projectPath)/src/StreamJobs/StreamJobs.asaproj -outputpath $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/StreamJobs'
```

But the build stream Analytics project step got wrong with below log:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTmpv.png)
Could somebody correct me?

Comment: Please use the azure-stream-analytics tag to help triage

Answer (score 1):

There is a new npm package available https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-streamanalytics-cicd that solves some issues when running on a Windows image, maybe this will help your issue as well.